# Is it possible to build a radar that is shielded behind one meter of ceramic material and still detect people 500 meters away?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radar

I saw that there are radars which can detect people behind walls so I wonder what are the limitations of radars when it comes to detecting people behind solid objects and if radars can have thick radome made out of ceramic material.